# Is there any APIs available to convert webpage to mobile webpage?

Tags: mobile, html, mobile-website

One of the goals in my project is to convert a standard webpage to mobile friendly webpage.
Can anybody help me find APIs for developing an algorithm which does this?

Comment: The aspect ratio & user experience is different between desktop & mobile version. You don't want to have your website directly converted. However, you can look into jQuery Mobile. It provides a lot of functions that creates a mobile website.

Comment: For converting page for mobile website, I have started working on another approach. In this approach, I have started extracting information from desktop websites. I am still wondering how to render those information for mobile devices. If anybody have any idea please post your suggestions.

Comment: To add to @ShivanRaptor, the reason you wont find API's for this is because, very often the content of your page will change, in addition to how it looks.  Many people choose to have a completely different page, and start from scratch design wise (although, you can still use alot of the same content).  JQuery Mobile is a good place to start for that.  Other people use things like Twitter Bootstrap to come up with one design that works for both desktops and mobile devices

Answer (score 2):

Mobile webpage is a usual webpage but written special to be displayed on mobile devices. You can add media queries (CSS3) to set additional styles for pages with special characteristics (in this case - mobile screen). For example:

```
@media screen and (max-device-width:480px )
{
    .your_css_class
    {
        font-size: 0.8em;
    }
}
```

This code will change font size for devices with screen size less than 480px.
Also, You can use such properties as: device-aspect-ratio, device-pixel-ratio, orientation(portrait/landscape).

Answer (score 0):

there are no specific apis that i know of, as 'webpage' can mean many different things. Often sites will have 10-item navigations, with drop-downs containing another ten-items each. a simple push-button conversion would not be very effective. 
the proper approach would be to design and build with both in mind.